# Efficiently finding rows within 31 days of other rows

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large dataframe (>5GB) which has rows with the following information:

`PatientID    StudyDate    Modality   SliceNo   Filename`

Each row consists of a slice in a 3D medical image, and for modality I have `PET` and `CT` which are two different types of medical scans. For instance, I could have:

```
PatientID    StudyDate    Modality   SliceNo   Filename
000000001    2017-08-01   PT         0         XXXXX
000000001    2017-08-01   PT         1         XXXXX
...
000000001    2017-08-01   PT         100       XXXXX
000000001    2017-04-01   PT         0         XXXXX
000000001    2017-04-01   PT         1         XXXXX
...
000000001    2016-08-01   CT         0         XXXXX
000000001    2016-08-01   CT         1         XXXXX
...
000000001    2016-08-01   CT         100       XXXXX
000000001    2017-04-15   CT         0         XXXXX
000000001    2017-04-15   CT         1         XXXXX
...
000000001    2017-04-15   CT         100       XXXXX
...
000000002    2016-07-01   PT         0         XXXXX
000000002    2016-07-01   PT         1         XXXXX
...
000000002    2016-07-01   PT         100       XXXXX
000000002    2015-07-21   PT         0         XXXXX
000000002    2015-07-21   PT         1         XXXXX
...
000000002    2015-07-21   PT         100       XXXXX
000000002    2014-07-01   PT         0         XXXXX
000000002    2014-07-01   PT         1         XXXXX
...
000000002    2014-07-01   PT         100       XXXXX
000000002    2015-08-05   CT         0         XXXXX
000000002    2015-08-05   CT         1         XXXXX
...
000000002    2015-08-05   CT         100       XXXXX
```

Now I would like to find the `PT` per patient which correspond to a `CT` scan, where correspondence is defined if it has been made less than one month before the `CT` scan. The other scans can be dismissed (dropped). In general there could be multiple CT scans, and multiple PT scans, but each CT should have one scan associated to it. For instance if the date of the CT scan would be 2017-04-01, all PT scans between 2017-03-01 and 2017-04-01 would qualify.

What is an efficient way to select those PT scans which satisfy the condition: for this patient there is a CT scan at most one month further in time?

For the example, and patient `000000001` the CT of 2016-08-01 will have no associated PT scan (which is fine), but the PT scan of 2017-04-01 will be selected because the CT scan of 2017-04-15 has been made at most 31 days after the PT scan. So, in this case, the PT scan of 2017-08-01 is filtered out. All slices (`SliceNo`) (there can be a different number of slices per scan) with this condition should be filtered. For patient `000000002` only the PT scan of 2015-07-21 is kept.

Comment: What does "one month before" exactly mean? If the `CT`'s date is `2016-08-15`, what are the valid dates for `PT`?

Comment: @JoergVanAken 2016-07-15 to 2016-08-15 would be valid PTs!

Comment: Could you please provide some more sample data and the expected output? I've got some ideas but I am not sure if they are applicable.

Comment: @JoergVanAken Tried to expand it a bit. In brief all PT scans of a patient which have not been made at most one month before a CT scan of the patient should be filtered.

Comment: Hi Jonas, did you see my answer?

Comment: @JoergVanAken Thanks a lot, not yet, I will check it out today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm does not cover all cases but I hope that it will help either.

At first we ignore some columns because we are in fact only interested in `cols = ['PatientID', 'StudyDate', 'Modality']`. So we write

```
df = df[cols].sort_values(cols).drop_duplicates()
```

Now we determine the `CT` and `PT` periods:

```
df['Modality_'] = df.groupby(['PatientID'])['Modality'].shift(1).fillna(method='bfill')
df['Group'] = (1-df['Modality_'].eq(df['Modality'])).cumsum()
```

Next we calculate the maximum and minimum date in each period

```
agg = df.pivot_table(index=['PatientID', 'Group'], columns=['Modality'], values=['StudyDate'], aggfunc=['max', 'min'])
```

Finally we extract the `PT` and the `CT` data. Because a `PT` period is always followed by a `CT` period, we can shift the formergroupwise by one and compare them directly

```
pt = agg.loc[:, ('max', 'StudyDate', 'PT')].groupby(['PatientID']).shift(1)
ct = agg.loc[:, ('min', 'StudyDate', 'CT')]
```

We want to choose the dates where the offset is less then 30 days:

```
ok = ct - pt < pd.offsets.Day(30)
ok = ok[ok == True].to_frame()
```

Now we are done:

```
print(ok.join(ct.to_frame()))
                    0 (max, StudyDate, CT)
PatientID Group                           
1         2      True           2017-04-15
2         4      True           2015-08-05

print(ok.join(pt.to_frame()))
                    0 (max, StudyDate, PT)
PatientID Group                           
1         2      True           2017-04-01
2         4      True           2015-07-21
```